# SimpleDateFormat String to Day of Week

Tags: android, string, simpledateformat, date-formatting, dayofweek

I've got a SQLite Database in Android where the date of an specific Event is saved as a `String`. I got the `Date` by a `DatePickerDialog`.

My Events get shown in an `ListView` and for that I want to order them by date and get the day of week from every `String`.

I know I have to convert my `String` to `SimpleDateFormat` and then get the day and make Event comparable. But all I get is a `ParseException`.

That's the `String` I insert into my Database:

```
 private void handleDateDialog() {
    setDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(CreateEvent.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,dateSetListener,year,month,day);

            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month += 1;
            String input = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            dateSelected.setText(input);
        }
    };
}
```

This is what I got from Stack Overflow by reading other questions:

```
public String getDayOfWeek(){
    String eventDate = this.getDate();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(eventDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dateFormat.applyPattern("EE");
    String dayofweek = dateFormat.format(date);
    return dayofweek;
}
```

And this is how I try to get the new `String` dayOfWeek into my `ListView`:

```
try {
    holder.day_of_week.setText(individualEvent.getDayOfWeek());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I always get this error in Android Monitor:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

So, I assume I've made something wrong in my Database.

When show my date `String` it shows like this: `28-10-2017`

I don't know why this isn't formatable.

Comment: Interested to see what `String eventDate = this.getDate();` this returns. I mean what's the format that you save in the DB? You mentioned "28.10.2017" and "28-10-2017" in your dialog picker. Which is it? Debug and find out.

Comment: The message *"Cannot format given Object as a Date"* usually happens because `SimpleDateFormat#format` method requires a `java.util.Date` as parameter, and you're probably passing another type to it. In `dateFormat.format(date)`, where is this `date` variable defined? You should pass `myDate` instead.

Comment: Oh yeah I made a typo in the question. Of course it returns the date like this: 28-10-2017

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change your code as :

```
public String getDayOfWeek(){
    String eventDate = this.getDate();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    try {
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(eventDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dateFormat.applyPattern("EE");
    String dayofweek = dateFormat.parse(myDate);
    return dayofweek;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below methods:
Keep the format standard and same for all

```
 /**
     * Parses @date to String in provided @format
     *
     * @param date   Date
     * @param format Convert to Format
     * @return formatted date string
     */
    public static String DateToString(Date date, String format) {
        if (date != null) {
            try {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                return dateFormat.format(date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
 /**
     * Parses String to date in provided {@link Format } as String
     *
     * @param date   String date
     * @param format Format
     * @return Date
     */
    public static Date StringToDate(String date, String format) {
        if (date != null && !date.isEmpty() && date.length() > 0) {
            try {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                return dateFormat.parse(date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses date String to date String in provided {@link Format } fromFormat to toFormat as String
     *
     * @param date       String date
     * @param fromFormat fromFormat
     * @param toFormat   toFormat
     * @return Format String date
     */
    public static String StringToString(String date, String fromFormat, String toFormat) {
        if (date != null && !date.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
                Date tempDate = formatter.parse(date);
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
                return dateFormat.format(tempDate);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As your date is 28.10.2017 in this pattern so You need to change your dateformat as follows:-

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: Sorry, this is of course right but you just discovered a typo in my question !